# What is a 'delta function optical pulse'?

Tags: optics, laser, dirac-delta-distributions, photonics

What is a 'delta function optical pulse'? I suspect this means that the optical pulse can be modelled as having the properties of the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), but then what does it mean to say that an optical pulse has the properties of the Dirac delta function or can be modelled as having the properties of the Dirac delta function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's the intensity (rather than the field strength)  of the pulse that's being treated as a delta function, it means the duration of the pulse is very short, and the total energy in the pulse is finite.